# Konvajs Group inside Group and rotation

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

I have a case where I have a parent `Group` and inside that, 1 `rectangle` for showing the boundary of parent group and child `groups` with `Circle` and `Text` for label.

What I need is when I rotate the parent `Group` I need to rotate only the `Rect` and the child `Group` should not rotate.

What I tried is inside the rotate function I filtered the child Groups like below and gave a reverse

```
       this.rotation = function(degrees) {
            group.rotation(degrees);
            var childGroup =  group.getChildren(function(node){
               return node.getClassName() === 'Group';
            })
            childGroup.each(function(item){
               item.rotation(-degrees);
            });                
            App.layer.draw();
        };
```

I might have up to 100 child Groups, Is there any performance issues doing this or is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Isn't it better to rotate just a rect and not parent group?

Comment: @lavrton I cannot rotate the Rect alone, its basically like shown in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/tvgsu5br/49/